# insert space before and after tag <br>

Tags: javascript, regex

Some regEx to insert blanks before and after 
 tag

My string:

```
test
:)

test
:)
test

:)

test
```

result in JS:

```
test<br>:)<br><br>test<br>:)<br>test<br><br>:)<br><br>test
```

RegEx to insert spaces:

```
test <br> :) <br> <br> test <br> :) <br> test <br> <br> :) <br> <br> test
```

It's possible? thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use `replace()` with your regex.  Something like this would work:

```
var str = "test<br>:)<br><br>test<br>:)<br>test<br><br>:)<br><br>test";

str = str.replace(/<br>/g," <br> ");
console.log(str);
```

Result:

> test <br> :) <br>  <br> test <br> :) <br> test <br>  <br> :) <br>  <br> test